# Order confirmation not being sent

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, ce-1.9.1.0, confirmation

after upgrading from Magento CE 1.9 to 1.9.1 order confirmations not being sent :(. I am using aoe sheduler and I am thinking that's looks fine or not?

[image]

But the exception log contains for example after a paypal express order the following:

```
2015-01-10T08:12:09+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail(Array
(
)
)' in /home/magento/www/lib/Varien/Object.php:653
Stack trace:
#0 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(634): Varien_Object->__call('queueNewOrderEm...', Array)
#1 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(634): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail()
#2 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->place('EC-28N558743076...')
#3 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->placeOrderAction()
#4 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('placeOrder')
#5 /home/magento/www/app/code/community/Mdl/UnderConstruction/Controller/Router/Standard.php(72): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mdl_UnderConstruction_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/magento/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/magento/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Hope you can help me, because sending order confirmations manually isn't a solution for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you cleared cache, flushed apc/OPcache (if in use), ran compilation process (if in use), here is a small list of things to check:

- Check if all 1.9.1 files have been copies over
- Open `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` and look for `queueNewOrderEmail` method
- If the method does not exist you don't have latest file
- If the method exists check if some third party module is rewriting the class and check your local code pool for override of the given class

Comment: thank you so much, there was a useless local overwrite :/ ... but now aoe_scheduler say to core_email_queue_send_all "Mulitple tasks with the same job code were piling up. Skipping execution of duplicates" any suggestions?