# Error when creating order from admin panel (Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail)

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, bug

We are running Magento CE 1.9.3.8 and have noticed an issue when creating an order manually from the admin panel (Sales > Orders > Create New Order).

When we create an order the following error is returned immediately after pressing the "Submit Order" button:

```
Order saving error: Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail(Array () )
```

A screenshot of the error is below:

[image]

From [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51852/order-confirmation-not-being-sent) there was a suggestion to check for the presence of the `queueNewOrderEmail` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` - I can confirm this is present.

I also could not see any cases where `queueNewOrderEmail` was being overridden. Here's a list of files referencing that function:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php:    public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php:        $this->queueNewOrderEmail(true);
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php:            $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart/Api.php:                    $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php:                    $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping.php:                    $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php:                $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Paypal/Mep/Checkout.php:                $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Buy/Order.php:            if (method_exists($this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder(), 'queueNewOrderEmail')) {
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Buy/Order.php:                $this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder()->queueNewOrderEmail(false);
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Ebay/Order.php:            if (method_exists($this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder(), 'queueNewOrderEmail')) {
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Ebay/Order.php:                $this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder()->queueNewOrderEmail(false);
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Amazon/Order.php:            if (method_exists($this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder(), 'queueNewOrderEmail')) {
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Amazon/Order.php:                $this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder()->queueNewOrderEmail(false);
app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/Model/Event.php:                $this->_order->queueNewOrderEmail();
```

Here's what is logged in `var/log/exception.log`:

```
Trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php(1572): Varien_Object->__call('queueNewOrderEm...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php(1572): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php(499): Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create->createOrder()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController->saveAction()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

How can we troubleshoot this? The core code has not been modified yet it appears to be referring to core code in the errors.

Comment: Why this error shows `array()` in method `queueNewOrderEmail` It should be only "TRUE" or "FALSE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 1.9 have introduced email queue feature, might be Magento_Sales_Model_Order.php class file should be overwritten by any module and those email queue related functions may be missing in that older class.

Comment: This was the issue - app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php was copied to app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php and had customisations. We've deleted the file and now all is well. Thanks.